# i cannot open my playstore application, using my google account

Tags: google-play-store

Everytime i open the play store store, it always directsme to the playstore setting where redeem appears and directing me to type my google password. just as i typed my password, connection problem always appears, where signal is strong.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! I've just re-tagged your question (from what you wrote, this has nothing to do with root-access). Please take a look at our [google-play-store tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info), which contains some first-aid hints for all kind of playstore issues, and see if your issue is covered – or some of the more generic solutions help you.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Server Error! Play Store failing](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27859/server-error-play-store-failing/118746#118746)

Well you need to delete hosts file, which is done via root privileges, without root you can't delete that file and I am afraid that play store won't work without deleting this file.

Comment: Please explain what does `hosts` file has anything to do with the problem? More specifically, which entry or entries in that file are the cause of issue?

Comment: Actually, it's not any of the entry which blocks access to the play store. Hosts file is a list of ip addresses that your device or perhaps your google play services can access. Sometimes this file gets messed up so that even if the entries are correct, play store won't open, and the only way to get it working again is to delete the file itself. The file is located in system/etc.

Comment: You could also save the file with another name and let play store make another hosts file and maybe after some time you can have a look at both to compare and find the root of your problem. I did once but find no wrong entries at all.

Comment: Normally, the hosts file remains very much empty with two entries of localhost. What is this thing that can mess up with it?

Comment: Well, not at all, many applications that require google play services, will automatically register an IP address for itself in the hosts file, if it has another IP address that is not already registered. Once my hosts file had about 26 IP addresses. Sometimes an unregistered IP address, could be the issue.

Comment: But many times, this for gets messed up by play store, like interrupted downloads, or like unsupported app, downloaded by other means. Sometimes ip addresses conflict with each other and could also be due to any as blocker, using lucky patcher or any other app to block ads.